# Robot test script that checks if an element exists and assigns its attribute values to a variable

Tags: dom, automated-tests, integration-testing, robotframework

In my Robot test automation script, I'm trying to detect if an element exists or not.  If it does, I'm trying to set a variable to the value of element's attributes.  If it doesn't exist, I'd like to set that variable to empty.  I can't for the life of me get this to work though:

```
My Feature Step Keyword
    :FOR  ${rowIndex}  IN  @{rowIndexes}
    \   ${xpathColumnIndex} =  Evaluate  ${columnIndex} + 1
    \   ${xpathRowIndex} =  Evaluate  ${rowIndex} + 1
    \   ${rowImageExist} =  Element Exists  table[contains(@class,'datatable')]/tbody/tr[${xpathRowIndex}]/td[${xpathColumnIndex}]/img
    \   Run Keyword If  ${rowImageExist}  ${rowAutoBidStatus} =  Get Element Attribute  jquery=tbody tr:eq(${rowIndex}) td:eq(${columnIndex}) img@data-status
    \   Run Keyword Unless  ${rowImageExist}  ${rowAutoBidStatus} =  ${EMPTY}
    \   Log  ${rowAutoBidStatus}

Element Exists
    [Documentation]  Determines if the desired element exists
    [Arguments]  ${xpath}
    ${imageCount} =  Get Matching Xpath Count  ${xpath}
    ${imageExists} =  Evaluate  ${imageCount} > 0
    [Return]  ${imageExists}
```

It keeps saying Non-existing variable ${rowAutoBidStatus} on the "Run Keyword If" keyword.  I've tried other combinations, like Set Variable If, but I think robot expects me to give it a value instead of another keyword to evaluate.  The problem is, I can't run the keyword "Get Element Attribute" until I make sure that the element exists.  Otherwise it will throw an error.

There has got to be a simple way to do this.  Its not that complicated and I can't imagine I'm the only person that has run into this problem.

Comment: I just tried "Set Keyword If" (http://pastebin.com/VPP47wW9) and it says evaluating condition "jquery=...." failed: SyntaxError.  I've gotten this before, with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Overview**

You are using [Run keyword if](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Run%20Keyword%20If) incorrectly. You must give it a keyword as the first argument after the condition, not a variable reference. It will return whatever the keyword returns, which you can save in a variable.

In other words, instead of this (using pipe-separated values for clarity):

```
| | # incorrect
| | Run keyword if | <some condition> | ${variable}= | some keyword
```

... you need to do this:

```
| | # correct
| | ${variable}= | Run keyword if | <some condition> | some keyword
```

If the keyword is *not* run, the variable will be set to `None` (ie: the same value that is in the automatic variable `${None}`)

**Example using your code**

In your case, you would replace the `Run Keyword If` and `Run Keyword Unless` statments with a single `Run Keyword If`:

```
${rowAutoBidStatus}=  Run Keyword If  ${rowImageExist}  Get Element Attribute  jquery=tbody tr:eq(${rowIndex}) td:eq(${columnIndex}) img@data-status
```

If you really want the value to be `${Empty}` rather than `${None}`, starting with Robot Framework 2.7.4 you can add an `ELSE` clause. It would look something like this (I'm going to spread it across multiple lines for clarity:

```
${rowAutoBidStatus}=  Run Keyword If  ${rowImageExist}  
...  Get Element Attribute  jquery=tbody tr:eq(${rowIndex}) td:eq(${columnIndex}) img@data-status 
...  ELSE  
...  Set variable | ${Empty}
```

Comment: I did not know that "Run Keyword If" could be used that way!  I always thought it had to be in the first column, because all the examples I found online had it used that way.  Nor did I know about the ELSE clause.  I tried out your suggestion and it worked brilliantly.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score -2):

I finally got it!

```
My Feature Step Keyword
    :FOR  ${rowIndex}  IN  @{rowIndexes}
    \   ${xpathColumnIndex} =  Evaluate  ${columnIndex} + 1
    \   ${xpathRowIndex} =  Evaluate  ${rowIndex} + 1
    \   ${xpathNextRowIndex} =  Evaluate  ${xpathRowIndex} + 1
    \   Get Element Info  //table[contains(@class,'datatable')]/tbody/tr[${xpathRowIndex}]/td[${xpathColumnIndex}]/img  data-status  data-attributes

Get Element Info
    [Arguments]  ${xpath}  ${attribute1}  ${attribute2}
    ${imageExist} =  Element Exists  ${xpath}
    ${attr1Locator} =  CATENATE  SEPARATOR=  xpath=  ${xpath}  @  ${attribute1}
    ${attr2Locator} =  CATENATE  SEPARATOR=  xpath=  ${xpath}  @  ${attribute2}
    Run Keyword If  ${imageExist}  Get Element Attribute1  ${attr1Locator}
    Run Keyword Unless  ${imageExist}  Set Element Attribute1 To Empty
    Run Keyword If  ${imageExist}  Get Element Attribute2  ${attr2Locator}
    Run Keyword Unless  ${imageExist}  Set Element Attribute2 To Empty

Get Element Attribute1
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${attributes} =  Get Element Attribute  ${locator}
    Set Test Variable  ${elementAttribute1}  ${attributes}

Set Element Attribute1 To Empty
    Set Test Variable  ${elementAttribute1}  ${EMPTY}

Get Element Attribute2
    [Arguments]  ${locator}
    ${attributes} =  Get Element Attribute  ${locator}
    Set Test Variable  ${elementAttribute2} ${attributes}

Set Element Attribute2 To Empty
    Set Test Variable  ${elementAttribute2}  ${EMPTY}

Element Exists
    [Documentation]  Determines if the desired element exists
    [Arguments]  ${xpath}
    ${imageCount} =  Get Matching Xpath Count  ${xpath}
    ${imageExists} =  Evaluate  ${imageCount} > 0
    [Return]  ${imageExists}
```

It looks like there are some occasions where I cannot chain keywords together, otherwise they don't get evaluated by robot correctly.  As long as I passed a keyword to "Run Keyword If" and "Run Keyword Unless", then it worked fine.  So I just made separate keywords for getting the element attributes and for setting the variable to empty.

Comment: What do you mean "got it two days later"? You only asked the questino 5 hours ago, according to the website.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion.  I meant two days ago, in reference to when I started writing this robot test, not when I asked the question.  I had been working on this since about Wed morning.  After trying a half a dozen ideas, googling for answers, and asking my team members for help, I finally posted it to StackOverflow.  I kept working on it afterward and finally came up with a solution.  Again, sorry about the confusion.  I'll delete that sentence from my response.

Comment: This doesn't really answer your question, it just shows a bunch of extra code. Somebody else who has the same problem as you probably won't learn anything from this answer without going line by line to try and understand the solution.

Comment: Well, it was a work around I was able to devise.  Not the ideal solution, but at least its something so if someone has a similar solution it might lead them to a solution.